# Repopulating page with previous values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a validation that needs to be done in controller. If it fails I need to go back to the view action back again with all values populated as it is on the page.
Is there a simple way to do that (using incoming params map).

Comment: Why does the validation need to be done in the controller? If you are following the standard rails mantra of "Fat models and skinny controllers" then the validation should all be in the model. You are making your life complicated by trying to do too much in your controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the basic way all Rails controllers and scaffolds work. Perhaps you should try generating scaffolds?

```
def create
  @banner_ad = BannerAd.new(params[:banner_ad])
    if @banner_ad.save
      flash[:notice] = 'BannerAd was successfully created.'
      redirect_to :action => "show", :id => @banner_ad
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
end
```

I populate a `@banner_ad` here, attempt to save it, if it fails, I return to the form and the @banner_ad object is available to me. I then need to have a form that uses the Rails form helpers to populate the values from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the flow of your app, really.

If the validation fails, you could pull the data out fo the database ...

```
if invalid?
  @model = model.find(:id
end
```

Otherwise you might need to store the original values in hidden fields in the view and use those.

Comment: If validation fails, the data shouldn't even be in the database. I don't know much about RoR, but it should still be sitting in the `POST` variable, no?

Comment: it's a new record so data has not been persisted to database. Data is coming from the screen and is in params hash. If validation fails at controller level (usually validation in RoR is at model level) the page needs to refresh with same data. Like rendering "new" action again just that with values prepopulated.